# How can I place a "Multiple startup projects" selector on the toolbar in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Having his feature in VS is great, and setting these up is also comfortable on this dialog box:
[image]

But if I want to switch from a "single startup project mode", to one of the items in the list above, I have to navigate back to this dialog. Is there any means to put a dropdown alongside the "single project" dropdown that would do just that? I could not find it among the items that can be placed on the toolbar. I am aware of the *SwitchStartupProject* plugin, but that's on the one hand an overkill for this, on the other hand, I had issues with it.

[image]

**[Update 24.03.21]**

What Happened??? The list under the green rectangle disappeared altogether in the latest version!

**[Update 24.03.28]**
The new feature does exactly what I needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj2YGHQ9a94

Comment: I guess I will have to write an extension for myself...

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper has something like that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).